SQLite returning zero records
I have exhausted all options and my brain is fried, with that said, I'm using visual studio enterprise 2022 I have installed the NUGET package System.Data.SQLite into my project.
In DB Browser for SQLite I created the database file with two tables.
documentTypes:
CREATE TABLE "documentTypes" (
    "docTypeID"   INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "docType"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "active"    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY("docTypeID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

documentFields:
CREATE TABLE "documentFields" (
    "fieldID"   INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "docType"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "fieldName" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "fieldDataType" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "active"    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY("fieldID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

Inserted some data:
INSERT INTO documentTypes (doctype) VALUES ('FUNDING NOTICES');
INSERT INTO documentTypes (doctype) VALUES ('CANCELS');
INSERT INTO documentTypes (doctype) VALUES ('WHOLESALES');
INSERT INTO documentTypes (doctype) VALUES ('DEALER TRADE');
INSERT INTO documentTypes (doctype) VALUES ('FACTORY');
INSERT INTO documentTypes (doctype) VALUES ('SC, CL, GAP STATEMENTS');
INSERT INTO documentTypes (doctype) VALUES ('RESERVE STATEMENTS');

INSERT INTO documentfields (docType, fieldName, fieldDataType) values ('FUNDING NOTICES','DATE','dte');
INSERT INTO documentfields (docType, fieldName, fieldDataType) values ('FUNDING NOTICES','STORE','text');
INSERT INTO documentfields (docType, fieldName, fieldDataType) values ('FUNDING NOTICES','LIEN HOLDER','text');
INSERT INTO documentfields (docType, fieldName, fieldDataType) values ('FUNDING NOTICES','AMOUNT','currency');

Data is there:
Select * from documentTypes;


select * from documentFields;


In my application when I run this code the query returns the data:
Dim SQLiteconn As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString())
Dim sqlitecmd As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT docTypeID,doctype FROM documentTypes WHERE active=1;", SQLiteconn)
Dim dt As New DataTable
SQLiteconn.Open()

Dim dr As SQLiteDataReader = sqlitecmd.ExecuteReader()

If dr.HasRows Then
    dt.Load(dr)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
       lstvDocTypes.DataSource = Nothing
       lstvDocTypes.DataSource = dt
       lstvDocTypes.ValueMember = dt.Columns(0).ToString
       lstvDocTypes.DisplayMember = dt.Columns(1).ToString
    End If
End If
SQLiteconn.Close()

and I populate the List View:

When I select a value on the list view it should load the data from the table documentFields into the second list view:
Dim SQLiteconn As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString())
Dim sqlitecmd As New SQLiteCommand($"SELECT * FROM documentFields WHERE docType = '{strDocType}';", SQLiteconn)
Dim dt As New DataTable
Try
    SQLiteconn.Open()

    Dim dr As SQLiteDataReader = sqlitecmd.ExecuteReader()

    If dr.HasRows Then
        dt.Load(dr)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            lstvDocTypeFields.DataSource = Nothing
            lstvDocTypeFields.DataSource = dt
            lstvDocTypeFields.ValueMember = dt.Columns(0).ToString
            lstvDocTypeFields.DisplayMember = dt.Columns(1).ToString
        End If

    End If

    SQLiteconn.Close()

In debug mode I checked the first query against the table documentTypes, and the data reader has rows and populates the list view.

, then I select an item in the list view and check on that data reader and is empty.

I checked the select command and looks good, I copied and pasted it into the DB Browser and retrives the data.

I also noticed that if I inspect the data reader in debug mode, shows that it does have rows, but after the inspection shows no rows at all. It looks like is getting emptied when inspected; but that's a different issue that I'll take care of it.
Here's what I have done to find out what's going on, I removed the SQLite package and reinstalled it, updated the package, I have even tried to use the Microsoft.data.SQlite package and still no luck, if any of you can point me in the right direction I really appreciate it.

I want to thank everyone who took the time to at least read the question. I have found the answer:

Dim sqlitecmd As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM documentFields WHERE docType = @DocType;", SQLiteconn)
 sqlitecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocType", strDocType)

As suggested by Daniel A. White, at first didn't worked because I was enclosing the parameter in single quotations, after the removal; the query performs perfect.

don't use string interpolation for queries. use parameterized queries!

@DanielA.White I have done it with and without parameters, interpolation, just a string and I still get the data adapter empty.  Dim sqlitecmd As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT fieldID, fieldName FROM documentFields WHERE docType = '@DocType' AND active = 1;", SQLiteconn)
sqlitecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocType", strDocType)

Set the .DataSource after the Display & Value member properties. No need to If dr.HasRows and If dt.Rows.Count > 0. If this is a WinForms app, then you're populating ListBoxes not ListViews. The latter don't have data properties.

Unrelated to your issue, the first thing I would point out is that your documentFields should NOT have that docType column with values from the docType column of the documentTypes table. It should have a docTypeID column with values from the docTypeID column of the documentTypes table. It should be a foeign key to the primary key of the other table and docTypeID should be that primary key.

The following may be of interest; SQLiteDataAdapter

@dr.null Thank you for your observations, don't understand what difference it will make to add the datasource after. My bad on calling the listbox a listview, I did that because im using Syncfusion's library and that how they call the listbox. Last but not least, I know is an over kill to check for rows on the datareader, but I'm parsing it as a datatable and i just wanted to make sure there's data.

You're welcome. When you set the DataSource property of a ListControl control (ListBox, ComboBox) to null/Nothing, the property setter resets the DisplayMember property to String.Empty. So, the order is important here. Set Nothing to clear the current source, set the DisplayMember, and lastly, set the DataSource. See DataSource property in the source code.

If your problem is solved, it's better to write a self-answer than to edit the answer into the question.  I'm surprised that just replacing the inline value with a parameter solved the problem, but it's good that the parameterized query works as that's much better practice.

I have found the answer:
Dim sqlitecmd As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM documentFields WHERE docType = @DocType;", SQLiteconn)

 sqlitecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocType", strDocType)

As suggested by Daniel A. White, at first didn't worked because I was enclosing the parameter in single quotations, after the removal; the query performs perfect.

That's because the parameter already has a type (that of the associated variable). Parameter substitution works like variable substitution in a programming language. You only use quotes when there is a constant inside
